# Set value for enumerator object of unknown type

Tags: java, enums

Let's say we have got a lot of enumerations of types A, B etc..:

```
public enum A {SOME, STUFF}
public enum B {OTHER, STUFF}
....
```

Now, we have got an object with unknown enum type. Is there any way to set its value? I know that `Java` is a static type language, but maybe there is a workaround for this?

I tried something like:

```
 public Enum getStuff(Enum unknownEnum, String value) {
     try {
         return Enum.valueOf(unknownEnum.getClass(), value);
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         return null;
     }

 }
```

But this does not work because valueOf requires a strong type, right? Do you know of any way how to do this in `Java`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Enum.getDeclaringClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass()) method instead:

```
public boolean setStuff(Enum unknownEnum, String value) {
     try {
         unknownEnum = Enum.valueOf(unknownEnum.getDeclaringClass(), value);
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: thanks, this works :)! My method in the OP was bogus though... return value must be the enum of course. Maybe edit your post too.

Comment: as i remember, in java you are passing objects by value, so in your snippet `unknownEnum` should be set only in scope of this method.